# Attempted VirtualBox upgrade causes 16.04 to fail

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox

I was running 16.04 as a VM in VirtualBox 5.0.20 with Win 7 as host.

It had been running OK until a VB upgrade was tried (first to 5.0.26 then to 5.1). Both upgrades failed so VB 5.0.20 was reloaded but now 16.04 won't start properly.

Apparently the VM begins but without the expected GUI since a terminal session can be started using ALT+CTL+F1. Instead an error message - "***Virtualbox client failed to connect to virtual box kernel service (RC=verr_access_denied***)" appears on unrecognized desktop.

## Also the VM prompts for login keyring ID which it apparently accepts. What is going on?

*ADDITIONAL* -

## While in screen session i can see that 16.04.1 LTS is running. Also GNU/Linux **4.4.0.31-generic x86_64** (which i assume is the corresponding kernel). If so why does the err msg seem to say that Ubuntu virtual machine "failed to connect to VirtualBox kernel service" ?

Comment: This seems like a problem on the Windows host, so off-topic here.

Comment: Hello: i'm really a NEWBIE to: (a) Ubuntu (b) Ask Question. What do i do next?  Thanx.